# CMS to develop an aggregator of posts

Tags: templates, web, content-management-system, themes

I would like to know if there is a CMS where users sign up and create posts (with text, images and videos) and then these posts are displayed on the main page of the website. Posts can be voted. Posts can also be filtered by most voted, most recent and by tag name. Basically, it will be like the Stack Overflow website but instead of questions, users post a topic.

If such a CMS does not exists, what options are available to develop one in terms of existing CMS/templates/themes that I can customize or otherwise?

Comment: Actually, what you are trying to imitate/implement sounds more like Reddit than StackExchange.

Comment: @mike I did not know about reddit. I must surely be living in a cave.

Answer (score 0):

There is some alternatives to go on with. I would go with a PHP one since it's more widespread but they should all do the job. Here's 2 of them:

http://www.osqa.net/

http://www.lampcms.com/

You can find more by doing a Google search with the keywords "Q&A Platform".